# Can I call Perl from within python?

Tags: python, perl

I have searched a lot and I have understood that there exists inline::Python for putting in python code within Perl..
But I am looking for some means by which I can access modules and functions written in Perl by not writing any Perl code, through a python code.

Maybe, I am asking for too much?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is the sort of thing that the [Parrot project](http://www.parrot.org/) aims to allow. It's a VM that's supposed to be able to run various dynamic languages, including Python and Perl. I've no idea how ready it is for real use, though, and I've never seen any instructions for people wanting to *use* Parrot, rather than develop it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's [language services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html) to parse Perl and generate a Python AST (with an appropriate FFI for any modules written in C), but I have not seen such an undertaking before.

Comment: ... not to mention that Perl is extremely hard, if not impossible, to parse (statically). Also, Perl is not exactly a simple language. Bottom line: This is not an option.

Comment: @delnan: Python is not a simple language either, and yet it manages to be parsed.

Comment: Python doesn't have enough operators to fill a whole periodic table, for example ;) Perl has a dozen shortcuts and special cases for hundreds of things, and all these have to be covered by a Pprser. Python's grammar is nothing you'd hand to a student in a compiler construction course, but it is indeed manageable and quite "regular" (not as in regular language). Perl's grammar is many times as large and complex. As the saying goes, "Only perl can parse Perl".

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=44722 and many related nodes on Perlmonks.  In short, in order to parse Perl correctly, you need a Perl interpreter.